# How do I find the current NFS version of Windows 11?

Tags: nfs, windows-11

I am currently planning out a NAS and want to use NFS for the file share.

So I am wondering what the current version of NFS on Windows is and how to find it out when the NFS Feature is installed.

Answer (score 0):

> So I am wondering what the current version of NFS on Windows is and how to find it out when the NFS Feature is installed.

According to Microsoft's documentation it's NFSv2 and NFSv3.  Windows 11 for the purposes of this article is equivalent to Windows 10. In other words Windows 11 supports the same versions that Windows 10 supports.

| Operating Systems | NFS Server Versions | NFS Client Versions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows 7, Windows 8.1, Windows 10 | NA | NFSv2, NFSv3 |

Source: [Windows and Windows Server versions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/nfs/nfs-overview#windows-and-windows-server-versions)